# How to simulate output delay using sc_method but without using next_trigger() in SystemC?

Tags: c++, systemc

```
SC_MODULE(example) {

  sc_in < int > a, b;

  sc_in < int > out

  Void process() {

    // Output delay implement here

  }

  SC_CTOR(example) {

    SC_METHOD(process);

    sensitivity << a << b;

  }

};
```

Comment: The question should give some information about what problem you are trying to solve by modeling a delay through a method, as well as some information about why you think you need to use a method here (just in case we can suggest another option).

Answer (score 1):

You can define an event and create a timed notification for it within your `process` method. Then, whatever needs to happen at the end of your delay can be done through another process that is made sensitive to the event.

```
sc_core::sc_event delay_e;

void process() {
    delay_e.notify(<enter your delay here>);
}

void respond() {
    // Do what needs to happen at the end of the delay...
}

SC_CTOR(example) {
    // ...

    SC_METHOD(respond);
    dont_initialize();
    sensitive << delay_e;
}
```